# CSS Unicode checkmarks/ticks have turned green/red in Windows 8.1/Firefox Version 32

Tags: html, css, firefox, windows-8.1

After updating to **Firefox version 32**, all the heavy checkmarks/ticks in my website have been updated to a lovely none conforming radioactive green colour.

**This issue seems isolated to WINDOWS 8.1 and FIREFOX V32**

---

**UNICODE SAMPLES**

## (✔, ☑, ✖,)

```
U+237B ⍻ not check mark
U+2610 ☐ ballot box
U+2611 ☑ ballot box with check (GREEN)
U+2705 ✅ white heavy check mark
U+2713 ✓ check mark
U+2714 ✔ heavy check mark (GREEN)
U+2716 ✖ Heavy multiplication (RED)
```

**FIREFOX V32** *(Screenshot)*

[image: Firefox green tick]

**CHROME V37** *(Screenshot)*

[image: Chrome white tick]

This was not the issue in Firefox version 31
Ticks where managed using css `color` attribute like other text.

---

### QUESTION

1. How can the colour of unicode ticks be managed in all popular modern browsers?
2. Why, why, why? *(I can understand a default but overiding settings seems illogical, I bet this is a mobile/tablet compensation)*.

---

**SCREENSHOT OF THIS POST'S SOURCE VIEWED IN FIREBUG**
*Still Green!* :o

[image: Green Ticks in firebug]

---

## TEST AREA

Comment: I have tested Firefox v32 and Chromium v37 on Ubuntu, both ticks are white...

Comment: The screenshot is taken from the test area demo above. Very strange?

Comment: Just tested this in one of my projects in Firefox v32 and I get the same problem! Very strange!

Comment: It is really white :D

Comment: I suspect firefox has created defaults for ticks because of the way checkboxes are viewed in on touch devices.

Comment: Could you post a CSS calculation of this div with browser styles?, but maybe this wont help...

Comment: Ive added the unicode directly to the page above with a matching screen.

Comment: Still all ticks black on my `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0`, I really want to help you, but I cant because I havent this bug :(

Comment: I'm running x64 windows 8.1 pro. Perhaps the changes have not been applied to the Linux version of Firefox.

Comment: maybe this is the problem, sorry but I dont want to pay for Win 8.1 for test it :D

Comment: I am also on FireFox v32 but I can't see any color change for the ticks. By the way, I am on Windows 8 too.

Comment: This is understandable :) I appreciate your efforts though, thanks.

Comment: No problem, pleasure (+1 for question)

Comment: Just to add that I'm also using Windows 8.1 (Enterprise) and I most definitely see this issue :P. This is going to annoy me now that I know about it, must find an answer! :)

Comment: @Harry if you are on a windows release of Firefox 32 your the prime guinea pig. What you operating differently?

Comment: @Obsidian: Not so sure about that mate. I am also on Windows + FF v32 but there is no color change and I think the OS version shouldn't really be affecting the browser behavior. So there must be something else. I am not doing anything differently either mate. I just opened your CSS Deck Test Area link and all looks in white color and same for the chars in question also.

Comment: Tried disabling all firefox add ons and still green. :( I going to try some other computers...

Comment: Seems localized to Fx32/Win8.1. Does this happen regardless of the font-family setting?

Comment: @BoltClock Tried this in windows vista and no green. Which means this is somehow Microsofts fault lol.

Comment: Strangely only happens in Firefox though? It has to be partially either vendor's fault... can't know unless you dive into the Firefox source. Speaking of source... what does it look like in the inspector, or even View Source?

Comment: Yeah, definitely an issue with the font rendering engine.

Comment: Even firebug is outputting green! It seems Microsoft have updated windows but it affects the way firefox renders the markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the following URL which would appear document the cause of the issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1054780

In particular this post by :Gijs Kruitbosch seems to sum up the issue well and provides a possible work around:

> This is reproducible on Nightly on Windows 8.1. AFAICT Segoe UI Emoji
>   is new in Windows 8, and that's what's causing issues here.
>
> There might be a way to turn off Windows's coloring for the font
>   (apparently this exists in XAML, but perhaps only for Windows Phone,
>   and I don't know if they expose that any other way), which would be
>   one option.
>
> The simpler option seems to be using Segoe UI Symbol instead, which
>   has at least all of these characters (I'm unfamiliar enough with
>   unicode that I don't know if/when this is a complete substitution for
>   the Emoji variant of the font, and/or for what ranges).

The suggestion to use Segoe UI Symbol does appear to work, changing the CSS in your example to:

```
div {
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Segoe UI Symbol;
}
```

results in white ticks again.

**Updated CSS deck example:** http://cssdeck.com/labs/dzemruoi

If you don't want to surround the tick in it's own individual container to change the `font-family` it is possible to specify `Segoe UI Symbol` as a fallback and the tick will still appear correctly while the other text will be in the preferred font:

```
div {
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: arial, Segoe UI Symbol;
}
```

**CSS deck example with other text:** http://cssdeck.com/labs/gzgwlhpb

Comment: Well researched. Great job.

Comment: Thanks! Frustrated the life out of me when I saw it occurring in one of my projects! Didn't think a fix would be possible until I came across that bug report.